# How to constrain scaling and connection points

Tags: modeling, workflow

I have a blend file with a window frame with sashes and glass.  I want to group this and instance it, then scale the instances to use in many places with different size window openings.

I designed the parts so that the thickness of the wood can scale lengthwise, but not in width. This means that for vertical pieces, Z would scale, but nothing else.  For horizontal, X but nothing else.  For the glass panes, X and Z can scale.

The trouble is that when scaled up the vertical pieces will scale in Z proportionally.  But since the horizontal pieces are locked in Z, a gap forms where they sit on top of the vertical pieces.

This has the effect of all the pieces keeping their constraints, but the group looking like an exploded view instead of a window frame of a different size with the same dimensions on the lumber and glass thickness?

[image: Before Scaling Window Sash]

[image: After Scaling]

How can I make it so scaling acts as desired?

Comment: You can set your Pivot Point for scaling from a certain Point instead of your Objects origin - maybe this is what you're looking for... (it's a little Icon on the 3D views Header bar at the bottom).

Comment: changing the origin changes where the objects scale from, but I can't find a way to make it keep the parts attached.  It seems like I'd need an attachment constraint.  But so far what I was able to find in that area seems to nullify the scaling constraint.

Comment: Maybe some Screenshots may help to explain your situation/problem a little better? Greenshot is a great tool to capture some... (with a direct imgur-upload)

Comment: Added screenshot of objects before scaling, and after scaling with restricted dimensions.

Comment: @shanemgrey could you include a screenshot of your desired result? I believe the answer to your problem is Local Transforms, but I'm not certain what you're trying to achieve.